# Calling out specific cells like A15 using integer 'i'

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

How do you call out a specific cell in Excel 2010, like A5 or B5, when you are in a VBA loop?

At the top I have:

```
SubAA()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 16 To 19

Windows("WorkbookA.xlsm").Activate
Range("(A,i)").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("WorkbookB.xlsm").Activate
Range("C14").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Windows("WorkbookA.xlsm").Activate
Range("(B,i)").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("WorkbookB.xlsm").Activate
Range("C18").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False                 

Next i    

End Sub
```

There is an issue with `Range("A,i)").Select`.

I want to have this macro work for multiple rows, and just not one.  I had it working correctly for just row 15, where the command was `Range("A15").Select`.

I would actually love the macro to work until it reaches a blank row but this will do for now.  I will figure that out.

Comment: Use: `Cells(i, "A")`. But note that it is much more efficient not to select obejcts in code to manipulate them - it is almost never necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm lost as to what are you trying to do but to it looks like you want to copy contents from 'WorkbookA.xlsm' to 'WorkbookB.xlsm'.

```
For i=16 to 19
    Range("A"&i).Copy(Destination:=Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").Sheets().Range("C"&i))
Next
```

That code will copy contents of A16:A19 in currently open worksheet to C16:C19 in first sheet of workbook 'WorkbookB.xlsm'

Please elaborate on your problem and I'll give you more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the string and integer, as below:

```
Range("B" & i).Select
```